# How to pass object as paramaters to function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have defination of function:

```
def setup(self, **kwargs):
    pass
```

And calling this like:

```
params = {
        "advert_id": adv_id,
        "enabled": True,
        "from_hour": 2,
        "to_hour": 1,
        "interval": 0,
        "weekdays": [1]
    }

setup(params)
```

I tried to pass `params` as object, but it does not work. I know correct way is:

```
setup(advert_id=1,enabled=True,from_hour=3,to_hour=4,interval=0,weekdays=[])
```

Anyway I don't want to enumerate all parameters and want to pack it to object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack `params` in the function call:

```
def setup(self, **kwargs):
   pass
params = {
    "advert_id": adv_id,
    "enabled": True,
    "from_hour": 2,
    "to_hour": 1,
    "interval": 0,
    "weekdays": [1]
}

setup(**params)
```

Comment: Just add `**` before `params` in function?

Comment: `**` is dictionary unpacking, which aligns with your `**kwargs` (unpack all other keyword arguments, which in this case is all the keyword arguments)